# How do I make it so that a label and an entry widget is shown only after the press of a button?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have been trying to make this window for my management system project. I want it so that when I press each button, the label and other widgets corresponding to those buttons become visible and the required actions are taken by the user. I have tried the grid_forget method (with the label 'Add new product') but I think I have been doing something wrong here:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class Admin:
   
        
        

   def __init__(self, master) :
        def show(label):
           label.grid(row = 0, column = 0, padx = 250, pady = 50)
        self.master = master
        self.master.title('Admin Controls')
        self.master.geometry('600x400')
        
        frame = LabelFrame(self.master, bd = 5, relief = 'ridge', height = 390, width = 200).place(x=0, y=5)

        
        

        frame1 = LabelFrame(self.master, bd = 5, relief = 'ridge', height = 390, width = 360).place(x=220, y=5)
        label = Label(frame1, text = 'Add new Product').grid_forget()

        product_change = Button(frame, text= 'Edit Product', width= '20', height= '1', command = lambda : show(label)).place(x=20, y=100)
        student_change = Button(frame, text= 'Edit Student_Data', width= '20', height= '1').place(x=20, y=200)
        pass_change = Button(frame, text= 'Change Password', width= '20', height= '1').place(x=20, y=300)






if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()

    admin = Admin(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

this gives me an error.

In its working state(without this grid_forget bit of code), the window looks like this:

[image]

Please suggest some other method to do that or correct this one.

Comment: post the entire error code pls

Answer (score 1):

Consider this line of code:

```
label = Label(frame1, text = 'Add new Product').grid_forget()
```

It is setting `label` to `None` since that's what `.grid_forget()` returns. As a general rule of thumb you should always separate widget creation from widget layout. This is a very common mistake people make, and this rule of thumb completely eliminates that mistake.

Second, there's no point in calling `grid_forget()` if you haven't first called `grid` or `grid_configure` on that widget. Until then, there's nothing for tkinter to forget. So, either don't call `grid_forget()`, or first call `grid` so that tkinter knows where it belongs and then call `grid_remove()`. The difference between `grid_remove` and `grid_forget` is that `grid_forget` literally forgets everything about the widget. `grid_remove` on the other hand remembers where the widget was located so that a future call to `grid` without any arguments will restore the widget to its original place.

Third, there's no need to use an embedded function. Make it a proper method on the class. It makes the code a bit easier to understand. Using an embedded function provides no advantages over a normal method.

Put all of that togeter and your program should look something like this:

```
class Admin:
    def __init__(self, master) :
        self.master = master
        self.master.title('Admin Controls')
        self.master.geometry('600x400')

        frame = LabelFrame(self.master, bd = 5, relief = 'ridge', height = 390, width = 200)
        frame1 = LabelFrame(self.master, bd = 5, relief = 'ridge', height = 390, width = 360)

        frame.place(x=0, y=5)
        frame1.place(x=220, y=5)

        self.label = Label(frame1, text = 'Add new Product')

        # define where the label is to be positioned but then
        # remove it from display until the user clicks the button.
        self.label.grid(row = 0, column = 0, padx = 250, pady = 50)
        self.label.grid_remove()

        product_change = Button(frame, text= 'Edit Product', width= '20', height= '1', command = self.show_label)
        student_change = Button(frame, text= 'Edit Student_Data', width= '20', height= '1')
        pass_change = Button(frame, text= 'Change Password', width= '20', height= '1')

        product_change.place(x=20, y=100)
        student_change.place(x=20, y=200)
        pass_change.place(x=20, y=300)

    def show_label(self):
        self.label.grid()
```

---

As a final note, I would strongly encourage you to use `grid` or `pack` instead of `place`. `place` is useful in certain circumstances, but it isn't very responsive and requires much more work on your part to get a well-behaved layout.